# drag images only when image is touched

Tags: ios, xcode5

i have an image that i drag around in my screen but, no matter where i touch the screen the image come to my finger and start dragging and for all the video i watched and all blog and article all that people are showing is how to do so ... its not what i want .. what i want is to start dragging the image only when i touch the image .. heres my code

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

```
UITouch *Drag = [ [  event allTouches ] anyObject ];
Dot.center = [ Drag locationInView: self.view ];

[self checkCollison];
```

}

thank you

Comment: Instead of this use UIPangesture

Answer (score 0):

In your .h

```
IBOutlet UIImageView * YOURIMAGE;
```

In your .m

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == YOURIMAGE) {
        YOURIMAGE.center = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    }
}
```

Comment: i like how simple it is but its not working .. if i put your code in the dot doesn't move at all ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method use [UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Create and add a pan gesture to your `UIImageView` like:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDrag:)];
[yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

And write the selector method like:

```
- (void)handleDrag:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
    CGPoint velocity    = [recognizer velocityInView:recognizer.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
       // start tracking movement
    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
         // You can change position here, with animation
    }
 }
```